# How to make mplayer continue after pausing it via a named pipe?

Tags: bash, pipe, mplayer

Create a named pipe.

```
mkfifo /tmp/mplayer-control
```

Run it in slave mode

```
mplayer -slave -input file=/tmp/mplayer-control mymusic.mp3
```

Now in another terminal i can make mplayer `pause` or `quit`

```
echo "pause" > /tmp/mplayer-control
echo "quit" > /tmp/mplayer-control
```

How to make mplayer continue when to issue a command via `echo "pause" > /tmp/mplayer-control`.

All my failed tries.

```
echo "continue" > /tmp/mplayer-control
echo "go on" > /tmp/mplayer-control
echo "play" > /tmp/mplayer-control
```

Comment: Perhaps play? That seems to be a common opposite.

Comment: `echo "play" > /tmp/mplayer-control` can't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pause` is a toggle. So to resume after a `pause`, you send another `pause` command.